# Converting Pandas Series to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column in a pandas dataframe of type pandas.core.series.Series to a datetime.

I've seen multiple answers that say to do something like this:

```
DF['ABC'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['ABC'])
```

However, I get this error:

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Any ideas? I'm using Anaconda with Python 3 and all my packages are up to date.

Comment: Well the warning is because you did something prior to that line which you've not included, for instance did you slice or filter `DF` prior to that line? Where did this data come from? If you're reading from csv then you can parse the data on reading

Comment: IDK what happen before this `pd.to_datetime` , but pandas already suggested `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: Yes, I imported it from CSV and in a prior step I did slice the data using some inequalities on this datetime.